# How to ignore accessibility fonts resize in NativeScript?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm using NativeScript with Angular. 
Is there an attribute to specify on Labels/buttons to **ignore** the font increase due to accessibility settings?
I need a solution for both android and ios.
Thank you!

Comment: Why would you want to? What if a user needs to read something?

Comment: I want to control this on certain elements and increase only for the important ones, to create a suitable view for all modes.

Answer (score 1):

If anybody interested, I found a workaround of using FormattedString for Labels, this object does not scale.

Comment: Only because of a bug in NativeScript: https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/4028

Comment: Oh, thanks for this. Will have to find another solution when this is fixed, I guess

Answer (score 1):

I just had a look a NativeScript own code and noticed this:

https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/master/tns-core-modules/ui/text-base/text-base.android.ts#L216

You could try this:

HTML:

```
<Label text="Fixed size text" (loaded)="fixedFontSize($event)"></Label>
```

TypeScript

```
import { Label } from 'ui/label';
...
fixedFontSize({object}, fontSize = 20) {
  const label = <Label>object;

  if (label.android) {
   label.nativeView.setTextSize(android.util.TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, utils.layout.toDevicePixels(fontSize));

  }
}
```

This should lock the fontSize of the label, until the CSS is changed.