# Allow/prevent accessibility font resizing of a Label

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I am implementing font size accessibility in a NativeScript-Vue app.
I want to allow or prevent Label resizing through an XML attribute for both Android and iOS, but behavior and implementation on the platforms are different.

**Android**
All labels are scaled by default. If I want a label not to resize, I need to call the function `setTextSize` in the `loaded` event, following [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45090354/10513892).

```xml
<Label text="Not resizable" @loaded="$androidFixedLabelSize($event, 70)" />
```

```js
Vue.prototype.$androidFixedLabelSize = function({ object }, fontSize) {
    if (object.android)
    object.nativeView.setTextSize(android.util.TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, utils.layout.toDevicePixels(fontSize));
}
```

**iOS**
Labels are not scaled by default. To resize a label, I need to use [nativescript-accessibility-ext](https://github.com/Notalib/nativescript-accessibility-ext) plugin and add the attribute `accessibilityAdjustsFontSize`.

```xml
<Label text="Resizable" accessibilityAdjustsFontSize="true" />
```

Having to add one attribute for fixed Android and one for resizable iOS is a bit cumbersome.

I was thinking of having all labels resizable by default, and specify if I want one not to resize through a directive or an attribute.
Can I achieve this through a custom directive? Or something else?

---

## Update

I was able to prevent resizing on Android through a directive without hardcoding font size, but there is a problem: `update` is triggered only for few labels. `el.nativeView.android` in `bind` and `inserted` hooks is undefined.

```js
Vue.directive("noresize", {
    update: el => {
        if (el.nativeView.android) {
            el.nativeView.android.setTextSize(android.util.TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, el.nativeView.fontSize);
        } else {
            // iOS code
        }
    }
});
```

On iOS, I would like to simply set `accessibilityAdjustsFontSize="false"`, but this implies that it is true by default.

So the next question is: how do I set `accessibilityAdjustsFontSize="true"` on all Label components on iOS?

Comment: You can of course do it with custom directive, I believe that's the whole reason of choosing frameworks like Vue or Angular over NativeScript Core. But 120 labels on screen? I hope you are aware of ListView component, if possible use it for long list of content. Also FYI, you can use px unit by simply specifying font size in px in CSS (font-size: 15px).

Comment: Using a custom directive, the Label nativeView object I access in the hooks comes without `setTextSize` (moreover, `android` or `ios` properties are shown undefined until `update` hook).
A ListView is not eligible for my 120 max label page (worst scenario). I'm not having rendering delays using simply labels.
Lastly, setting font size through `setTextSize` is the only approach I found for avoiding auto scaling.

Comment: You might not be accessing it with right attributes. Can you share the Playground sample for the directive? Between I too have auto scaling support in my apps, I didn't have to do anything on Android, not entirely sure why you need to use px. DIP unit (default) is still good. For iOS, I took the plugin logic but implemented same on Font level, so it would scale automatically for all components.

Comment: I am using `setTextSize` with px basing on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45090354/10513892), which is the only workaround I found to prevent auto scaling. I didn't examine the code in depth. Looking closely at [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextSize(int,%2520float)), I see can use DIPs

Comment: Sorry, are you trying to avoid auto scaling or implement it? Because in iOS it's not handled by default, you would use the plugin if you want to support auto scaling.

Comment: I have implemented auto scaling on iOS. I want to be able to allow or ignore auto scaling on my labels through a simple attribute for both Android and iOS. While on iOS it is handled by the plugin (`accessibilityAdjustsFontSize="true|false (default)"`), on Android it is not, and the `setTextSize` workaround is the only solution I found to prevent auto scaling.

Comment: As I already mentioned, simply add a class to those labels or set the fontSize attribute with unit. If you have issues in your custom directive, please share the sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Morten Sjøgren, developer of [@nota/nativescript-accessibility-ext](https://github.com/Notalib/nativescript-accessibility-ext), I was able to add a global event. Accessibility resizing is now applied on all Label components, unless the attribute `noResize` is true.

app.js

```
import '@nota/nativescript-accessibility-ext';
import { Label } from 'tns-core-modules/ui/label';

// code

Label.on(Label.loadedEvent, ({ object }) => {
    if (object.noResize) {
        if (object.android) {
            object.nativeView.setTextSize(android.util.TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, object.fontSize);
        }
    } else {
        object.accessibilityAdjustsFontSize = "true";
    }
 });
```

```
<Label text="Don't resize" noResize="true" />
```